# Do math on string count (and text parsing with awk)

Tags: parsing, awk

I have a 4 column file (input.file) with a header:

```
something1 something2 A B
```

followed by many 4-column rows with the same format (e.g.):

```
ID_00001 1 0 0
ID_00002 0 1 0
ID_00003 1 0 0
ID_00004 0 0 1
ID_00005 0 1 0
ID_00006 0 1 0
ID_00007 0 0 0
ID_00008 1 0 0
```

Where "1 0 0" is representative of "AA", "0 1 0" means "AB", and "0 0 1" means "BB"

First, I would like to create a 5th column to identify these representations:

```
ID_00001 1 0 0 AA
ID_00002 0 1 0 AB
ID_00003 1 0 0 AA
ID_00004 0 0 1 BB
ID_00005 0 1 0 AB
ID_00006 0 1 0 AB
ID_00007 0 0 0 no data
ID_00008 1 0 0 AA
```

Note that the A's and B's need to be parsed from columns 3 and 4 of the header row, as they are not always A and B.

Next, I want to "do math" on the counts for (the new) column 5 as follows:

```
(2BB + AB) / 2(AA + AB + BB)
```

Using the example, the math would give:

(2(1) + 3) / 2(3 + 3 + 1) = 5/14 = 0.357

which I would like to append to the end of the desired output file (output.file):

```
ID_00001 1 0 0 AA
ID_00002 0 1 0 AB
ID_00003 1 0 0 AA
ID_00004 0 0 1 BB
ID_00005 0 1 0 AB
ID_00006 0 1 0 AB
ID_00007 0 0 0 no data
ID_00008 1 0 0 AA

B_freq = 0.357
```

So far I have this:

```
awk '{ if ($2 = 1) {print $0, $5="AA"} \
else if($3 = 1) {print $0, $5="AB"} \
else if($4 = 1) {print $0, $5="BB"} \
else {print$0, $5="no data"}}' input.file > output.file
```

Obviously, I was not able to figure out how to parse the info from row 1 (the header row, edited out "column 1"), much less do the math.

Thanks guys!

Comment: `...how to parse the info from column 1...`??

Comment: meant row 1 (the header row), sorry about that

Comment: more specifically, I was not able to (e.g.) parse the "A" from column 3 of the header row and put it (twice) in column 5 of a subsequent "1 0 0" row.

Comment: Now I understood, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a more structured approach...

```
NR==1 {a["100"]=$3$3; a["010"]=$3$4; a["001"]=$4$4; print; next}   
      {k=$2$3$4; 
       print $0, (k in a)?a[k]:"no data";
       c[k]++}
END   {printf "\nB freq = %.3f\n",
       (2*c["001"]+c["010"]) / 2 / (c["100"]+c["010"]+c["001"])}
```

**UPDATE**
For non binary data you can follow the same logic with some pre-processing. Something like this should work in the main block:

```
for(i=2;i<5;i++) v[i]=(($i-0.9)^2<=0.1^2)?1:0;
k=v[2] v[3] v[4];
...
```

here the value is quantized at one for the range [0.8,1] and zero otherwise.

To capture "B" or substitute set `h=$4` in the first block and use it as `printf "\n%s freq...",h,(2*c...`

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly for the question as it was asked. How would the code be changed to allow for a range of values for each of columns 2, 3 and 4 in the main body of the input file (Specifically, if I wanted to accept a range >= 0.8 && <= 1 (i.e. 0.8 -1) as an acceptable call for A or B)? For example, if the actual row numbers were 0.84 0.15 0.01, I would still want an AA call (instead of no data). Please let me know if I should create a new question from scratch. (I assumed that I could adjust for the range myself, but your answer is beyond my ability to edit).

Comment: I placed the additional (pre-processing) script between "END {" and "printf" in the original script. I generated a valid but unchanged output compared to the original script. I am not sure if I put the additional script in the wrong place or if it isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: It should be in the main block, before the `k=` line (and use the new definition of 'k`)

Comment: It worked!! Now to spend some time figuring out exactly what you've done! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Instead of using "\nB freq", how do incorporate the actual value of column 4 of the header row (a string that varies in different input files) into the last line of the output file? Thanks